# Как настроить .htaccess файл

Tags: html, веб-программирование, .htaccess, apache, домен

У меня есть директория, в которой лежит индекс.хтмл, а также папка pages. В ней лежат guide, marathons и privacy. Что мне надо прописать в .htaccess файле и где он вообще должен лежать, чтобы при переходе, например, на guide.html был путь "domen.ru/guide", а не "domen.ru/pages/guide/guide.html"?
Спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 0):

лежать должен там же корневой папке сайта, видимо там же где и `index.html`.
Прописать надо что-то вроде

```
RewriteRule ^guide/?$ pages/guide/guide.html [L]
```

Это касается преобразования входящих ссылок, то ест как сопоставить то что ввел пользователь, тому, что лежит на сервере.

Если у вас в файлах есть прямые ссылки вида `/pages/guide/guide.html` то их лучше заменить. Можно для них сделать редирект, но это какой-то костыль будет